# Can we call a function within a function in Java?

Tags: java

If we declare a method to be static, then without needing to instantiate we can call that method anywhere within the class body.

If we do not declare a method to be static, then an object can be instantiated and we call the method.

Now if we do not declare a method to be static and also do not instantiate, can we call a function within a function?

EDIT:

I understand now, that my hunch was right. We cannot call another function within a function unless there static or object instantiation.

But in Java applets I remember seeing a function being called from another function.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Container;

public class MethodCall extends JApplet
{
    public void init()
    {
        String output = "";
        JTextArea outputarea=new JTextArea(10,20);
        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.add(outputarea);

        int result;
        for(int x=1;x<=10;x++)
        {
            result = square(x);
            output += "Square of " + x + " is " + result + "\n";
        }//end of for loop

        outputarea.setText(output);
    }//end of init()

    public int square(int y)
    {
        return y*y;
    }//end of square()

}//end of class MethodCall
```

See square() function

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: what you saw is probably methods of the super class, which are available (if you extend applet of frame, you get most of their methods as well)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No You can't.**

If a method is not **static**, then it has to be called from an instance of some class. Even in the examples given here, like

```
public class A{

    private void foo()
    {
        bar();
    }
    private void bar()
    {

    }
}
```

You don't call bar just as itself, you call it on the current instance of A, which is like `this.bar()`

**EDIT**

In your example, you already have an instance of `MethodCall` when you are in `init` (otherwise you couldn't call it). so the call to `square()` is actually `this.square()`. the same for `getContentPane()` which is a method of JApplet (which is the super class of `MethodCall`)

Comment: Downvoter - I would like to hear what is not correct with this answer.

Answer (score 12):

Your question is not really clear, but here's a quick summary:

```
class A {
    public static void foo() {
        bar();      // illegal, no object
        foo();      // legal, implicit
        A.foo();    // legal, explicit
        A a = new A();
        a.bar();    // legal - we call a non-static function on an object
    }

    public void bar() {
        bar();      // legal, implicit
        this.bar(); // legal, explicit
        foo();      // legal, implicit
        A.foo();    // legal, explicit
    }
}
```

Note that the calls to the functions within themselves in this case are infinitely recursive.

Comment: Just a note: the call bar() within the method public void bar() is also infinitely recursive.

Comment: @Danilo I added the note in the bottom to avoid too much information in the comments, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can as long as it's visible to the function. Say for example the calling function and the called function are in the same class or a sub class. If its a sub class the called method scope should be default, protected or public.

Comment: This is inaccurate. You actually call it on `this` in those cases.

Comment: Correct. But the question asked was without initiating an Object.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're asking if you can call a function within a function in a standard non-static Java method.

That's possible, as long as the function you want to call is within the same class or class hierarchy, or the function you're calling is itself static.

Answer (score 0):

That should work:

```
public class CallTest {

    public static void someMethod(){
        System.out.println("blabla");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CallTest.someMethod();
    }

}
```